# Imported txt file in java, but came out in output as "null"

Tags: java, null, formatting, jcreator

This code is not done yet, but I'm keep getting the problem where the txt file (cpu.txt) becomes "null" in the output, does anyone know where I did wrong? Thanks.

This is the output:

--------------------Configuration: --------------------

```
BINGO CALL IS: G50

PLAYER CARDS:
  B   I   N   G   O           B   I   N   G   O
1   21  38  58  68  
5   29  31  51  73  
15  20  F   59  67  
4   30  39  53  74  
11  28  33  48  69  
7   30  32  49  69  
8   27  35  58  63  
3   17  F   57  68  
11  18  45  52  71  
12  16  33  54  70  

CPU CARDS:
  B   I   N   G   O           B   I   N   G   O
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    
null    null    null    null    null    


B   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  
I   16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  
N   31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  
G   46  47  48  49  *   51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  
O   61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75
```

current points available: 0 point.
     1. Daub board
     2. Call Bingo!
     3. Use bonus (1000 points)
     4. Next call

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Bingo_D {

    public static void callBoard(int[] un, int turns) {


            int t = 1;
            int i = 1;

            int[] bingo = new int[76];
            System.out.print("B" + "\t");
            String star= "nothing";
            for ( i=1; i < bingo.length; i++){

                bingo[i] = i;

                for (t = 1; t < un.length; t++){
                if(un[t] == bingo[i]){ //un = call, bingo = board
                star = Integer.toString(bingo[i]);
                star = "*"; 
                System.out.print(star + "\t");
                break;
                } else if (t == i){
                System.out.print(bingo[i] + "\t");
                    } 
                }
                if (bingo[i] % 15 == 0 ){
                System.out.println();

                } if (bingo[i] == 15) {
                System.out.print("I" + "\t");
                } if (bingo[i] == 30) {
                System.out.print("N" + "\t");
                } if (bingo[i] == 45) {
                System.out.print("G" + "\t");
                } if (bingo[i] == 60) {
                System.out.print("O" + "\t");
                }
            }
        }    
              public static String randomCall(){
              Random object = new Random();
              int number = 1+object.nextInt(75); 

              if (number > 0 && number < 16 ){
              System.out.print("B" + number );
              } else if ( number > 15 && number < 31){
              System.out.print("I" + number );
              } else if ( number > 30 && number < 46){
              System.out.print("N" + number );
              } else if ( number > 45 && number < 61){
              System.out.print("G" + number );
              } else {
              System.out.print("O" + number );
              } 
              String real = Integer.toString(number);
              return real;
         }

           public static boolean checkWinner(String[] check){
           int b = 1;
           int i = 6;
           int n = 11;
           int g = 16;
           int o = 21;
           //vertical victory
           while(true){
           if (n == 13 && check[b].equals("*") && check[i].equals("*") && check[n].equals("F") && check[g].equals("*") && check[o].equals("*")|| 
               n == 38 && check[b].equals("*") && check[i].equals("*") && check[n].equals("F") && check[g].equals("*") && check[o].equals("*")){
           return true;
         } else if (check[b].equals("*") && check[i].equals("*") && check[n].equals("*") && check[g].equals("*") && check[o].equals("*")){
              return true;
               } else {
           if(b < 5 || b > 25 && b < 30) {
              b++; i++; n++; g++; o++;
             }else if( b == 5) {
              b+=21; i+=21; n+=21; g+=21; o+=21;
             } else {
             break;
                }
            }
        }
        //horizontal victory
        int m = 1;
        int p = 2;
        int x = 3;
        int u = 4;
        int w = 5;
     while (true){
      if (x == 13 && check[m].equals("*") && check[p].equals("*") && check[x].equals("F") && check[u].equals("*") && check[w].equals("*")|| 
          x == 38 && check[m].equals("*") && check[p].equals("*") && check[x].equals("F") && check[u].equals("*") && check[w].equals("*")){
        return true;
      } else if (check[m].equals("*") && check[p].equals("*") && check[x].equals("*") && check[u].equals("*") && check[w].equals("*")){
        return true;
      } else if (m < 46){
        m+=5; p+=5; x+=5; u+=5; w+=5;
      } else {
        break;
      }
  } //diagonal victory
          if (check[1].equals("*") && check[7].equals("*") && check[13].equals("F") && check[19].equals("*") && check[25].equals("*")||
              check[5].equals("*") && check[9].equals("*") && check[13].equals("F") && check[17].equals("*") && check[21].equals("*")||
              check[26].equals("*") && check[32].equals("*") && check[38].equals("F") && check[44].equals("*") && check[50].equals("*")||   
              check[30].equals("*") && check[34].equals("*") && check[38].equals("F") && check[42].equals("*") && check[46].equals("*")){
              return true;

              } else 
              return false;
          }  


            public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{

            int [] stars = new int[51];
            int [] starstwo = new int[51];
            int e = 0;
            String[] b = new String[51];
            String[] btwo = new String[51];
            int tob = 1;
            int i = 0;
            int itwo = 0;
            int cou = 1;
            int coutwo = 1;
            String star = "";
            String startwo = "";



            int totalBonus = 0;
            int bon =0;
            int secondChoice = 0;
            int thirdChoice = 0;

            for( int turns = 1; turns < 200; turns++){

            System.out.print("BINGO CALL IS: ");
            String replace = randomCall();
            int[] call = new int[76];
            int randomNum = Integer.parseInt(replace);
            call[turns] = randomNum;

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();

                File player = new File("player.txt");
                Scanner second = new Scanner(player); 
                System.out.println("PLAYER CARDS:");
                //Reformatting the txt file
                System.out.format("%3s%4s%4s%4s%4s\t\t\t%3s%4s%4s%4s%4s%n", "B", "I", "N", "G", "O", "B", "I", "N", "G", "O");
                for (i= 1; i < 51; i++){
                for( cou = 1; cou < 51; cou++){
                if ( i == stars[cou]){
                b[i] = second.next();
                b[i] = "*";
                star = "*";
                System.out.printf("%4s", star + "\t");
                }
            }  
                if ( !star.equals("*")){
                b[i] = second.next();
                System.out.printf("%s", b[i] + "\t");
                }   
                if(star.equals("*")){
                star = "nothing";
                }
                 if(i == bon && !b[i].equals("*")){
                b[i]= second.next();
                b[i]= "F";
                System.out.printf("%s","F" + "\t");
            }
                 if(i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                } 
            }   

                System.out.println();

                File cpuu = new File("cpu.txt");
                Scanner secondtwo = new Scanner(cpuu); 
                System.out.println("CPU CARDS:");
                //Reformatting the txt file
                System.out.format("%3s%4s%4s%4s%4s\t\t\t%3s%4s%4s%4s%4s%n", "B", "I", "N", "G", "O", "B", "I", "N", "G", "O");
                for (itwo= 1; itwo < 51; itwo++){
                for( coutwo = 1; coutwo < 51; coutwo++){
                if ( itwo == starstwo[coutwo]){
                btwo[itwo] = secondtwo.next();
                btwo[itwo] = "*";
                startwo = "*";
                System.out.printf("%4s", startwo + "\t");
                }
            }  
                if ( !startwo.equals("*")){
                btwo[itwo] = secondtwo.next();
                System.out.printf("%s", btwo[itwo] + "\t");
                }   
                if(startwo.equals("*")){
                startwo = "nothing";
                }
                 if(itwo == bon && !b[i].equals("*")){
                btwo[itwo] = second.next();
                btwo[itwo] = "F";
                System.out.printf("%s","F" + "\t");
            }
                 if(itwo % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                } 
            }   

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            callBoard(call,turns);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("current points available: " + totalBonus + " point." );
            System.out.println("     1. Daub board");
            System.out.println("     2. Call Bingo!"); 
            System.out.println("     3. Use bonus (1000 points)");
            System.out.println("     4. Next call");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            long var = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            int choice = input.nextInt();

            if(choice == 1){
            long varl = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;


            if (varl - var <= 3){
            int bonus = 400;
            for ( e = 1; e < 51; e++){
            if ( replace.equals(b[e])){
            totalBonus+=bonus;
            System.out.println("you daubed " + replace + " on your board(s), " + bonus + " points earned.");
            stars[tob]=e;
            tob++;
            break;
            }else if(e==50){
             int penalty = 500;
             totalBonus-=penalty;
             System.out.println("You do not have "+ replace + " on your board(s), 500 points penalty");
            }
        }

        } else if(varl - var == 4) {
            int smallBonus = 200;
            for ( e = 1; e < 51; e++){
            if ( replace.equals(b[e])){
            totalBonus+=smallBonus;
            System.out.println("you daubed " + replace + " on your board(s), " + smallBonus + " points earned.");
            stars[tob]=e;
            tob++;
            break;
            }else if(e==50){
             int penalty = 500;
             totalBonus-=penalty;
             System.out.println("You do not have "+ replace + " on your board(s), 500 points penalty");
            }
        }

            }else{
            for ( e = 1; e < 51; e++){
            if ( replace.equals(b[e])){
            System.out.println("you daubed " + replace + " on your board(s).");
            stars[tob]=e;
            tob++;
            break;
            }else if(e==50){
             int penalty = 500;
             totalBonus-=penalty;
             System.out.println("You do not have "+ replace + " on your board(s), 500 points penalty");
                        }
                    }
                }
              secondChoice = input.nextInt(); 
          if (secondChoice == 2){
          if (checkWinner(b) == true){
            System.out.println("BINGO! congratulation, you have won!");
            System.exit(0);
                } else {
            System.out.println("CHEATER! you lose!");   
            System.exit(0);
                }
            }

            if(secondChoice == 3){

            if( totalBonus >= 1000 ){
           Random object = new Random();
             bon = 1+object.nextInt(50); 
             for(int w = 0; w < 10; w++){
             if( b[bon].equals("*")){
            bon = 1+object.nextInt(50);
                 }
             } System.out.println("Bonus daubs at " + b[bon]);
            if (!b[bon].equals("*")) {
            System.out.println("Bonus daubs at " + b[bon]);
            }
        } else {
        System.out.println("Not enough Bonus points.");
         }
         thirdChoice = input.nextInt();
    }      

            if (secondChoice == 4 || thirdChoice == 4){
         for ( k = 1; k < 51; k++){
            if ( replace.equals(starsCpu[k])){
             System.out.println("The computer daubed " + starsCpu[k]);
            starsCpu[com] = k;      
                com++;
                    if (checkWinner(a) == true){
                    System.out.println("BINGO! , computer has won!");
                    }
                    }else if (k == 50){
                    System.out.println("The computer do not have " + replace);
                    }
                }
            }
        }//end of first choice    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the text file becomes null?  Do you mean it gets erased?  Replaced with a file that contains the word "null"?  Or do you mean that one variable is not set to the value that you expect?  Please clarify.

Comment: yeh the file itself gets erased and everynumber in the file gets replaced with the word"null".

Comment: So where's the piece of code that writes to the file?  I can't see it above - there's too much other stuff.  That would be a good place for you to start looking for the problem.  You may find stepping through with a debugger to be a useful process.

Comment: " File cpuu = new File("cpu.txt");
  Scanner secondtwo = new Scanner(cpuu); 
            System.out.println("CPU CARDS:");
            //Reformatting the txt file
            System.out.format("%3s%4s%4s%4s%4s\t\t\t%3s%4s%4s%4s%4s%n", "B", "I", "N", "G", "O", "B", "I", "N", "G", "O");
            for (itwo= 1; itwo < 51; itwo++){
            for( coutwo = 1; coutwo < 51; coutwo++){
            if ( itwo == starstwo[coutwo]){
            btwo[itwo] = secondtwo.next();
            btwo[itwo] = "*";
            startwo = "*";
            System.out.printf("%4s", startwo + "\t");
            }"

Comment: I don't see how that writes to the text file.  All I see you writing to is `System.out`.  Unless you redirected it on the command line or something.  Is that what you did?

Comment: Please, split this code into small pieces and then test each part and you will find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading and discarding a whole lot of stuff in the file, when you write

```
    if ( itwo == starstwo[coutwo]){
            btwo[itwo] = secondtwo.next();
            btwo[itwo] = "*";
```

Then, later when you write

```
            btwo[itwo] = secondtwo.next();
            System.out.printf("%s", btwo[itwo] + "\t");
```

there's nothing left to read.

But I still don't understand how that causes your text file to get erased and replaced, like you said it does.  There is NO CODE IN YOUR SAMPLE that will erase or write to your text file.